# Controlling the display order of custom field sets that are shown both in a webform and in CiviCRM, via the webform_civicrm integration module

Tags: webforms, civicrm

I've created a webform that is integrated with my CiviCRM implementation. The webform has five major sections to it, each of which is reflected by a custom field set within the CiviCRM module as shown below.

All five custom field sets are linked to a specific activity type as indicated in the first screenshot. The five custom field sets are ordered, by weight, in the list of custom field sets within CiviCRM because I want the summary information displayed first to the administrator viewing the activity.:

[image: This screenshot shows the order of the custom field sets as defined in CivicRM]

However I want the summary questions displayed at the end of the webform, as presented to the user, so I've used webform's flexibility to let me do that.

So far so good. But when I submit the webform, the CiviCRM activity record, when in view mode, reflects the field order as specified in the webform, rather than as specified in CiviCRM, which seems odd.

[image: This screenshot shows that the custom field set entitled "Report Evaluation - cover page" is the first to be displayed when viewing the activity record]

However, if I edit the activity record, the field order and field sets are as ordered in my original CiviCRM field definitions.

[image: And this third screenshot shows the relevant part of the edit page for the activity, showing the six custom field groups, collapsed, reflecting the same order as they were defined.]

How can I set it up so that the field order in the Activity record, when viewed rather than edited, reflects the order specified within CiviCRM?

(I'm aware that this question is more about CiviCRM than it is about Drupal per se, but given that CiviCRM is a Drupal module, and there's no SE site dedicated to CiviCRM - yet - I hope you'll bear with me and allow answers to this question.

Comment: A screenshot or two might help, this is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: Agreed, it was a tad convoluted. I've edited and included three hopefully useful screenshots that will hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Comment: It looks like you are using an older verison of CiviCRM - have you tried in 4.5? I remember seeing an issue go through recently that had to do with custom field ordering.

Comment: The site is currently on 4.4.6 I think. We're were holding off on moving to 4.5.x because of reported issues with the case management side of things, but I think that's now resolved and so I imagine we'll update soon. Hopefully that may resolve this annoying issue. I'll check out the issue queue and see if I can't find something on this.

Comment: Is this a case activity? I had run into that bug, and it's been fixed in 4.5.2. See CRM-15435 (the patch is easy to backport, and might be worth backporting to 4.4 LTS).

Comment: Aah, that's really useful to know @bgm, thanks. I did search the issue queue but couldn't find anything. This will further drive the pressure to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was resolved in CiviCRM 4.5.2, the relevant issue was [CRM-15435: Case ActivityView popups do not respect custom group weights](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15435).

Comment: Belated answer based on above comments, mostly to get this out of the "Unanswered" queue :) 
There's a CiviCRM SE site now! https://civicrm.stackexchange.com